# What determines the quality of loot in horadric caches?

Tags: diablo-iii

Ofcourse your character's level and the random factor affect what you get in the caches, but is there anything else that has influence on the loot from a cache? For example, does it matter on what difficulty I complete the bounties? Does it matter on which difficulty I open them? Anything else?

For clarification, I'm talking about the reward you get from completing all bounties in one act in adventure mode. A new feature in the Reaper of Souls expansion. Upon completing all bounties in one act you get a one time use cache which drops some loot when used. It usually drops a few crafting materials, some rift keystone fragments and a couple of blues and yellow. I've had one legendary so far out of 4 or 5 caches.

I understand there isn't nearly enough data from the community yet to answer this question based on results. But if someone had a link to a blue post explaining this or perhaps an ingame reference that answers this, that would be awesome.
Damn it, I might just spend the next few evenings farming normal - T1 caches and see if I get significant differences in drops :D.

Comment: I suspect difficulty obtained matters, but there's not enough crowdsourced data yet to tell how much it matters.  The only 2 legs I got from them were from T2 bags, but then the sample size there is way too small to tell.

Comment: @z- I agree there isn't enough data to conclude anything, I was wondering if someone had a link to a blue post or something. Thanks for replying :).

Comment: I've heard some people say that opening the bags in t6 increases chances of imperial gem drops, I don't know if that's true.

Comment: @z- Tonight I'm gonna farm like crazy. I'm gonna try to get one row in my stash with normal caches, one row with hard caches etc... Up to T2. I will post the results back tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#amhoradriccache). Caches have a greater chance to drop legendary items on Torment2+ difficult level.

> Now have an increased chance to drop Legendary items on Torment II -
>   VI

The cache will contain items that match the level of the game that the cache was received in. Even if you change to a higher level and open the cache. The level of the items will still be the level you received the cache.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but what determines the type of loot you get - the class of the character farming the cache, or the class of the character opening the cache?

Comment: Class of the character that receives the cache. Everything is determined as soon as you are rewarded the cache. Except what items actually drop.

Comment: @acedanger actually, the cache level is determined by the ilevel of the instance it was obtained at, while the smart loot is rolled at time of opening. therefore, the loot is determined at time of opening. you can farm on one character and open on another. http://www.reddit.com/r/diablo3/comments/226kn4/opening_horadric_caches_with_another_class/  note: this may be an unintended bug

Answer (score 12):

The difficulty and level of the game when you got the cache determines the quality of items inside it. Where you open it makes no difference.

I was speed-leveling another character last night by having them create a T6 Adventure game, and got quite a few cubes during the process. I saved some to test if opening them in a T6 level 70 game made any difference, and it did not.

The level and quality of items in the cube always matched the level and quality at the time I got the cube. For example, a cube obtained in a level 20 T6 game always dropped level 20 items, along with low level gems and crafting materials. It didn't matter if I opened it in a different level 70 T6 game, or later on in the same game once the low level char hit 50.

The level/quality of items is determined at the time you claim the cache, not at the time you become eligible for it. For example, if you become eligible for a cache at level 20, but don't claim it until level 60, you will have level 60 items inside.

Comment: This has been confirmed on the d3 forums too.  A chache's loot is determined when it drops, so it doesn't matter when you open it.  This is similar to unidentified items.  The item and it's level requirement etc are determined on drop, not on identification.

Comment: This is now incorrect. Difficulty has no impact on the quality of loot you get from a cache. Normal bags have the same chances as Torment bags.

Answer (score 4):

As of now, difficulty does *not* affect Horadric Caches. Originally, there was a bug which allowed Imperial gems to drop from Caches on Torment difficulty, but that has since been patched. As Horadric Caches are not affected by difficulty, they also cannot drop Torment-exclusive legendaries. This is also true of Kadala, the blood shard merchant.

Currently, only monster drops (including Rift Guardians) are affected by difficulty.

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12373027360?page=4#63)

Comment: No longer valid as of patch 2.0.5. http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#amhoradriccache

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm that I did receive imperial gems and 2 legs from the caches obtained in normal but opened on T6. I did not receive many, most were marquise.

Comment: I've received an Imperial Diamond just as a random drop in Hard (or maybe it was Master...can't remember if it was before or after I stepped up the difficulty - either way, I haven't started Torment yet) so the appearance of the gem doesn't mean that where you opened it made a difference.

Comment: A hotfix went in today (4/1): "Bounty bags now properly ignore Difficulty setting when opened. You can no longer get Imperial Gems or increased gold by opening them on a higher difficulty."