# Are there act specific legendaries from the horadric cache?

Tags: diablo-iii

Up until this point, I thought that the [Pauldrons of the Skeleton](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162112/what-is-the-proc-rate-of-the-special-ability-on-pauldrons-of-the-skeleton-king) king was act 1 only but I was wrong.  What are the legendaries that can only be obtained from a specific act's bounty bag?  Is the Ring of Royal Grandeur still act 1 only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161937/what-determines-the-quality-of-loot-in-horadric-caches

Comment: @Jutschge how is that a dupe? The other one is asking about quality of loot based on difficulty I'm looking for a list of cache only legendaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here is a great list I found](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/82430-ros-faq-reaper-of-souls-frequently-asked#cachelegs), that includes all known Act specific legendaries that you can get from Horadric caches.

- Avarice Band - Act 3 and Act 4
- Boots of Disregard - Act 3 and Act 4
- Burst of Wrath - Act 3 and Act 4
- Cloak of Deception - Act 2 and Act 4
- Coven's Criterion - Act 2 and Act 4
- Death's Bargain - Act 4 and Act 5
- Envious Blade - Act 3 and Act 4
- Gloves of Worship - Act 2 and Act 4
- Golden Gorget of Leoric - Act 1 and Act 4
- Helltrapper - Act 4 and Act 5
- Ilusory Boots - Act 2 and Act 4
- Insatiable Belt - Act 3 and Act 4
- Mad Monarch's Scepter - Act 1 and Act 4
- Overwhelming Desire - Act 3 and Act 4
- Pandemonium Loop - Act 4 and Act 5
- Pauldrons of the Skeleton King - Act 1 and Act 4
- Pride's Fall - Act 3 and Act 4
- Ring of Royal Grandeur - Act 1 and Act 4
- Salvation - Act 4 and Act 5
- Sanguinary Vambraces - Act 1 and Act 4
- Soulsmasher - Act 4 and Act 5

If you'd like to view the item, [I suggest following the link to the original post](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/82430-ros-faq-reaper-of-souls-frequently-asked#cachelegs), which will give you real time pop-ups of the items.

Comment: nice list. that is awesome.  Hrmm... based on that info act 4 bounty bags seems to be the best to go for?  it has a chance of dropping everything.

Comment: That's how I read it. If you're not looking for a specific item... seems like Act IV is your best choice.

Comment: Just to confirm, I got the Pauldrons of the Skeleton Kind in Act IV last night!